# Filter column on multiple criteria and copy to different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, filter, v8

I want to move filtered data from one sheet to a different sheet.

I can do this for a single filtered value ex: `Money` but I want to filter on multiple values from an array ex: `["Money", "Society", "Impacts"]`

I can not figure out how to loop through the `filterValues`  array and collect all the values from the different filterValues.

I just get the filtered values of rawData for the last value in filterValues

I can do this a different way but I am trying to get a better understanding of filtering

```
function myFunction() {
  var filterValues = ["Money", "Society"]; //filter values.
  var col = 5; // column "E".
  var sheetName = "Elements";

  var ss      = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht     = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rng     = sht.getDataRange();
  var rawData = rng.getDisplayValues();
  
  var out = rawData.filter(dataFilter);
  
  function dataFilter(arr) {
      return arr[col-1]== filterValues;
  }

  const osh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("A"); 
  osh.clear();
  osh.getRange(1,1,out.length,out[0].length).setValues(out);
};
```

tried this

```
for (var i = 0; i <= filterValues.length-1; i++) {
  var out = rawData.filter(dataFilter);
  
  function dataFilter(arr) {
      return arr[col-1]== filterValues[i];
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array.includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp) to check if the current row column e value is listed in your `filterValues` for your array filter function.

### Sample code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var filterValues = ["Money", "Society"]; //filter values.
  var col = 5; // column "E".
  var sheetName = "Elements";

  var ss      = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht     = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rng     = sht.getDataRange();
  var rawData = rng.getDisplayValues();

  var out = rawData.filter(dataFilter);
  
  function dataFilter(arr) {
    return filterValues.includes(arr[col-1]);
  }
  Logger.log(out);
  const osh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("A"); 
  osh.clear();
  osh.getRange(1,1,out.length,out[0].length).setValues(out);
};
```

### What it does?

1. Get the data range values
2. Filter the 2-d array values if column E value was found in your `filterValues` array.
3. Write the filtered array on the destination sheet.

### Output:

**Source Sheet: Elements**

[image]

**Destination Sheet: A**

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered issues regarding the solution so I could update accordingly.

Comment: Ron, thank you. , so, `filterValues.includes(arr[col-1])` is a concise way to loop/iterate over two arrays? this is essentially a double loop?

Comment: In your function `dataFilter(arr)` when used in `filter()` will iterate your 2-d array one-by-one. Example your 2-d array is `[[1,1],[2,2]]`. It will be checked as a 1-d array of `[1,1]` and `[2,2]` in `dataFilter(arr)`. You can put `Logger.log(arr);` inside the  `dataFilter(arr)` to visualize what i'm trying to say

Comment: i'm not sure if i fully understood your question though?. when i used `filterValues.includes(arr[col-1])` you just actually loop(single loop) `filterValues` and see if the argument `arr[col-1]` exist in the array

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question, the second part

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a basic filter function combined with array syntax like you'd use in SumProduct. Example: `=filter(List!A:A,(List!A:A="Society")+(List!A:A="Money"))`.

I don't think you'd need to use Google App Scripts. [See this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15cRBuBQBNL7-oIpG22YOgkQUm9lqFZHG_zhJrPSyAM4/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I do actually need it as a script though as I want to use it as a step in a series of transforming scripts

Comment: @Einarr thanks, I appreciate the click (assuming it was yours).  All is forgiven. Good luck.